# Navigating HTML Page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to scrape a website which contains [betting odds data](http://www.betezy.com.au/sport/soccer/game/725768).

The way the page is written, it lists the market names in a label tag which is not a parent of the selections, more of a separator for the page.

Using JSoup I can pull out all the selection data I want, but I don't know how to figure out what the preceding value for 'label' is for a selection. So in effect I have every selection and price on the page, but I can't resolve whether 'Brazil $4' relates to the World Cup market, the Highest Scoring Team or any other market.

The code I'm using to get the markets and selections is:

```
    Elements marketNames  = doc.getElementsByTag("label");
    Elements runnerNames = doc.getElementsByClass("selection");
```

Basically now I have a selection like "Brazil - $4.0". I want to also know what the previous label was, so I can refer to it as "Winner - Brazil - $4.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the previous label you can iterate over div tags so you could know about the order of the labels.

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div.sports_FfCell"); //gets the div part that has the information you want. 

for (Element div : divs) {      
     if (div.toString().contains("market")) //there is a market tag for the table labels (sports_FfCell market).
        System.out.print(div.text() + " - "); //no new line after the winner text.
     else
        System.out.println(div.text().replace("MULTI", "- ")); //it gets the MULTI part too, so i replace it.
}
```

Output:

```
Place Win World Cup 2014
Winner - Brazil - 3.75
Argentina - 5.00
Germany - 6.50
Spain - 7.00
Belgium - 21.00
...
```

Comment: Took me a few more hours but I finally figured out the same solution. I used a very similar approach but not as efficiently as yours. Thank you.